# From and To date in calendar selector not fetching required data

Tags: microstrategy

I created calendar selector on date attribute.

1. when I select only From date, I get a message'No data returned for this view'.
2. when I select only To date,I am able to fetch all data values.
3. when I select From date and To date together, I get a Message "No data returned for this view".
4. when I run the report without any date selection (empty dates), I am able to fetch all data values.

I need related data values between From date and To date as per date selection.

Comment: did you create it in a MicroStrategy Document or in a Dashboard? in the a Document selectors are punctual (like you have the = sign) filters

Comment: yes, i created microstrategy document.Could you please explain details steps on this..

Comment: find out the solution,attribute date is of date time datatype.